# use data when a resource exists, otherwise create a new one

Tags: terraform

terraform has resource and data. resource creates a new thing, while data refers to an existing thing.

Is it possible to do the following?
1) if a resource does not exit, create a new one by 'resource'
2) if it exists, refer to it by 'data'

For example,

```
# if not exists
   resource "a" "b" { name = ...}
# else 
   data "a" "b" {name = ...}

resource "c" "d" {
   field = "${element(concat(a.b.*.name, data.a.b.*.name), 0)}"
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem possible and doesn't look like it will be added according to [github issue #16380](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/16380)

Answer (score 0):

The [Hashicorp blog post about conditional creation of resources](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/develop/composition#conditional-creation-of-objects) answers a different question to what the OP asked.

The unfortunate answer is that with stock Terraform it's not possible to *check* whether a resource exists, only to *assert* either that it does (via a data source definition) or doesn't (via a resource definition), and alternate between these with a flag (often a boolean, but other data types can be used).

There are plenty of conceivable scenarios where *checking* if a resource exists would be a useful feature, but until data sources grow the capability to ignore errors and check for success/failure, custom providers or the [null resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/null/latest/docs/resources/resource) with the [local exec](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec) (or remote-exec) provisioner are required to work around this limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Terraform is a "desired state" system, which means you need to *tell it* what should be true about the remote system.

For Terraform's execution model to work, each object in the remote system must be managed by at most one Terraform configuration. "Managed by" means that there's a `resource` block that is bound to that remote object. A `data` block is how you can make use of an object that is managed by another Terraform configuration, or not managed by Terraform at all.

Terraform requires you to be explicit about whether you are managing an object or just depending on it because otherwise it would be unclear whether a particular configuration is managing an object or not. One way to think about that question is: should running `terraform destroy` delete the object? If the object is managed by the current Terraform configuration then yes, but otherwise no. If it were possible to do something like what you described then it would be unclear whether `terraform destroy` should destroy the object.

---

It is possible to write a module that can be *configured* to either manage or depend on a particular object. For example:

```
variable "existing_thing_id" {
  type    = string
  default = null
}

resource "thing" "example" {
  count = var.existing_thing_id == null ? 1 : 0

  # ...
}


data "thing" "example" {
  count = var.existing_thing_id != null ? 1 : 0

  id = var.existing_thing_id
  # ...
}

locals {
  thing_name = concat(thing.example, data.thing.example)[0].name
}
```

This works by varying the number of instances of `resource "thing" "example"` and `data "thing" "example"` depending on whether `var.existing_thing_id` has been set. The two `count` rules are opposites, so exactly one of the two will always be declared. `local.thing_name` will be the name either of the existing object that was passed in or of the object that is managed by this module.

The user of this module can then set `existing_thing_id` if they already have a "thing" managed elsewhere that they want to use, or can leave `existing_thing_id` unset if they don't have such an object and so wish this module to create one. The user of this module *must still explicitly decide* -- it must still be clear whether the overall configuration is managing this object or not -- but you can, if it's useful to do so, share the same module source code between those two cases.

If you can though, it's better to avoid this sort of complexity by explicitly designing your system architecture up front so that there is one clear owner for every object. That will make your system easier to understand for future maintainers who are using the Terraform configuration as a description of the intended architecture.

Answer (score -1):

[This](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/composition.html#conditional-creation-of-objects) blog post describes a way to accomplish what you're trying to do by using a variable of type `object` with the minimum required (shared) attributes and passing that in.

Comment: Instead of linking the blog post, it is a good idea to write the essential parts from it into your anser. The link could be outdated in the future.

Comment: 2nding @colidyre's opinion -- I'd upvote this answer if you would write out its essence.